# How to sync folders selectively across computers?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Is it possible to select which folders (outside the ubuntu one folder) are being synced to each machine ?
For instance i'd like to sync a data-heavy folder with most of my PC's but not with my netbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

In 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) you'll be able to use the “Ubuntu One Control Panel” to select which folders to do this in a nice graphical way.

However, the functionality has existed in the backend since at least 10.10. The act of selecting a folder to sync is called “subscribing” the folder, and is distinct from creating / deleting it (which is what is exposed via Nautilus).

Meanwhile you can access the functionality via `u1sdtool`: to list all the folders `syncdaemon` knows about, enter `u1sdtool --list-folders`; then you use the folder ids listed there to enter the id in `u1sdtool --subscribe-folder=folderid` (or `--unsubscribe`).

The default behavior is for syncdaemon to subscribe to folders automatically when they are created; you can change this by editing `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` (or `~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` to do it per user) and add a line `udf_autosubscribe = False` to the `[__main__]` section.